# XML to Word using custom paragraph styles and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word

I've got an XML file that contains mostly textual information (list of questions in [Moodle XML format](https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Moodle_XML_format)). I'd like to convert it to a document that can be opened by MS Word, but I'd like to maintain context (using paragraph styles) so I can convert it back to Moodle XML. Here's what I tried so far:

- I was excited to find several tutorials (e.g., [a](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-tips-for-using-word-as-an-xml-editor/)) about how to use XML in Word, but many of them are moot given the [result of the i4i patent dispute](http://www.i4i.com/x4w.htm).
- I made a prototype with RTF with XSLT, but the RTF styling and Unicode support is complex.
- I've seen a way to use `<p class="myCustomStyle">` with HTML documents which can be opened in Word. But HTML style sheets and mapping them to Word styles seems limited. I need styles that are "based on" (inherit from) other styles and it's not clear how this works using HTML classes and CSS.
- I've looked at OpenXML with Office. The `<w:blah>` tags are pretty easy to use, but I don't like the whole ZIP archive solution. This means styles go in one XML file, content in another, etc. I'm guessing I'll need another step beyond XSLT (some kind of script to do multiple transforms). I'm trying to keep it simple:

[image: Component diagram of problem]

Is there a way to make a single XML-like (not RTF) file that imports styled paragraphs into Word?

Comment: Wouldn't Microsoft Office Word 2003 XML format  suit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've looked at OpenXML with Office. The  tags are pretty easy
>   to use, but I don't like the whole ZIP archive solution. This means
>   styles go in one XML file, content in another, etc.

Then you'll want to check out [The Flat OPC Format](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/the-flat-opc-format.aspx), where the [OPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions) parts are represented in a single XML file rather than multiple files zipped together.

Comment: Flat OPC looks possible, and I found a simple example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11076023/1168342

Comment: Saving a document in Word 2010 as a "Word XML Document (*.xml)" appears to save as Flat OPC Format, and this appears useful to find an example of how custom styles are represented. This is to be confused with "Word 2003 XML Document (*.xml)" as it is a different format. I'm accepting this answer as it satisfies my question.